# Testing for duplicates in MYSQL by attempting insertion

Tags: mysql

I am writing a function that inserts a user into a MYSQL table. Initially I wrote the function such that it would first check for existing users with the same username with a `SELECT` statement. However, my table specifies the username column to be unique, so I realized that after I check to see if the user exists, the database checks a second time.

Is it better to just try to insert the row and see if there is an error or to explicitly check with a `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about your environment, programming language, load, performance etc I would say stick to what makes you feel good!

Both scenarios are not wrong ;)

Think and code for what the common scenario is. I mean, you are saying that this is for new registered users. So, how frequent do you think that the user will try to re-register ? Right! I would in this case maybe try to insert in first case.

Do you think you will have a high rate of insert-failure then do select-check first is good.

Comment: If I expected a high rate of failure, wouldn't I want to avoid an extra check to get rid of the overhead?

Comment: the cost of do a select-check upon high-rate-insert-failure will be much easier to take in this case (than the error handling in the db engine which can cost more). All can be measured, you can setup a load and run both scenarios to see your db engine behavior. As said, code for the common scenario if you are looking for performance gain

Comment: Interesting. I did not realize that the error handling in the db engine would have significant overhead (I guess it makes sense though). Ultimately, however, I intend all validation to be done client-side (via AJAX in this case). Because of this, I expect a low rate of failure, so I think I will INSERT first, ask questions later.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you are doing the checking.

When you do a `select` before the `insert`, you have a race condition.  Another user/thread could insert a duplicate record *between* the `select` and `insert`.  That is why you want to do the check in the `insert`.

In general, it is sufficient to do the check in the `insert`.  If you want to avoid the error, use `on duplicate key update`.  This is preferable to `insert ignore`, because `on duplicate key update` only handles errors regarding key duplication.  `Insert ignore` ignores all errors.

I would say not to bother with the check before hand, unless you have some particular reason.  Here are some reasons:

- You want to minimize the time that the table is locked, so you want to avoid asking questions such as "how long is the table locked when a duplicate occurs?".
- Intentional holes in your auto_increment columns bother you (actually, I'm not sure if this is an issue with MySQL).
- You are inserting multiple rows and want the ability to detect multiple duplicates for reporting back to users.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a check via an Ajax request for better end user experience if this is a Web based app.

Comment: I do plan to do this, but the question was regarding the create user function on the back end

Comment: If you have verified with your dB that a username does not exist allow the user to submit the form. Otherwise prevent the form from being submitted so you only have one dB check per username provided. I do not believe there is a need for another safety measure.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for INSERT IGNORE. On duplicate primary key insertion it will generate a warning instead of an error and you wont need to run the SELECT to check for duplicates.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Having read a bit of the documentation you linked to, this sounds like the opposite of what I want. Doesn't this prevent the exact error I wanted to use to detect duplicate usernames? It seems like this would result in the server saying "All done, your username now exists" when in reality nothing was done.